# Running jupyter notebook on HPC

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, cluster-computing, hpc

I am trying to open the jupyter notebook on HPC and access it on my local computer. For that I run the following command on my local computer-

`ipython notebook --no-browser --port=8889`

This shows the error-

`/share/apps/python_shared/3.6.5/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

What could be the reason for the error?

Comment: Search for the required file "libpython3.6m.so.1.0" and tune the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`/`PATH` if needed. If the file does not exist on your system, then the installation is probably broken.

Comment: The file is located in `/opt/python/lib` directory. What should I do to it?

Comment: So try running something like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/python/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ipython notebook --no-browser --port=8889` (eventually the same with `PATH`). It is not something normal so there is probably something wrong with the installation/configuration of the package anyway but it may solve (temporary) your problem.

Comment: Now it shows an import error- `ImportError: /share/apps/python_shared/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _Py_set_inheritable_async_safe`

Comment: This means that the shared library file is likely not compatible with the ipython notebook you use (ie different version). It may not be the correct one associated with the ipython package. Try to reinstall the package (and possibly python if this does not work).